# Export Firebird database to sql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, firebird, ibexpert

I have several databases in Firebird using IBExpert as the GUI admin. I am changing over to MySQL. I can use IBExpert to backup the database (which gives me the full structure and data) but the gbak format can't be read by phpMyAdmin. PhpMyAdmin has an export command that dumps the data and/or structure of the active database to an sql file. Is it possible to do something similar with IBExpert?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/) tool to generate a dump with inserts. However I am not sure if it is still maintained and works with the latest Firebird versions (it says it was tested against Firebird 1.0 - 2.1).

See [Export data from Firebird into pure SQL inserts/ export data from Firebird to MySQL](http://kosiara87.blogspot.nl/2011/03/export-data-from-firebird-into-pure-sql.html) for an example of how to use this tool:

> ```
> $> FBExport.exe -D "c:\DB\WL.FDB" -U user –P password -Si -V TEST -F test.out
> ```
>
> Where:
>   `Si` – means “export to SQL inserts” format
>   `V` – table name to export
>   `F` – output filename

Answer (score 1):

In IBExpert you can extract [Metadata](http://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/index.php?n=Doc.ExtractMetadata) but it will be in Firebird SQL dialect so if you use generator or sequence you will have problem with MySQL which not support this.

The best way is to use tools like [Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com/products.dbw.index.php) and use DataPump. There are many others tools which are able to make DataPump but I like this one.

CleverComponents also made [one](http://www.clevercomponents.com/downloads/dbc/dbcdownload.asp)

Why changing to MySQL ?

Comment: Had previously been using Delphi with FB as db. I'm not doing Delphi development anymore. My latest stuff is all PHP.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW the [FBExport](http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/) utility mentioned by Mark Rotteveel seems to work on Firebird 2.5 DBs i.e. DBs with ODS v11.2. Tested on Windows 10 recently and had no issues (except for some field types not exporting which I think is a limitation mentioned in the FBExport docs).

Have not tried it on any more recent DBs so YMMV with any DBs newer than ODS v11.2.